# Delete Adjacent Duplicates alternative code without delete

Tags: row, unique, abap, duplicates

I want to edit program thereby loop at `gt_ugtyt` table which is created by a database table. However I have a problem.

STDATE-STTIME-ENDDATE-ENDTIME (Field names)

[image]

I want to sum (ENDTIME-STTIME). It means "working time". But you can see that there are same rows as (STDATE-STTIME-ENDDATE-ENDTIME). Because we give twice confirmation in our multiple production process (That's not important. Just notice). I have to work with unique variables.

I defined a temporary table as `gt_ugtyt_temp` and wrote the following code

```
SORT gt_ugtyt_temp BY endat stdat sttim entim.

DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM gt_ugtyt_temp COMPARING endat stdat sttim entim.
```

But i want to loop in `gt_ugtyt` . I want to read and calculate unique rows as (STDATE-STTIME-ENDDATE-ENDTIME). But I don't want to write

```
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM gt_ugtyt COMPARING endat stdat sttim entim.
```

Because other codes are using all rows on gt_ugtyt .

Is there any code like (This is not real code :) ) :

```
READ UNIQUE ROWS FROM FROM gt_ugtyt COMPARING endat stdat sttim entim.
```

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more background information? The statement you're looking for doesn't exist. Without knowing why you don't want to copy the table or modify the table, it's hard to provide alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I don't clearly understand what you want to do, but, can't you copy the rows from `gt_ugtyt` to a local temporary table `lt_ugtyt_unique_rows` and then do the operations you need on it?

```
DATA:
  lt_ugtyt_unique_rows LIKE gt_ugtyt.

INSERT LINES OF gt_ugtyt INTO lt_ugtyt_unique_rows.

DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM lt_ugtyt_unique_rows COMPARING endat stdat sttim entim.

*Sum what you need with lt_ugtyt_unique_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

So `gt_ugtyt_temp` contains unique records, and `gt_ugtyt` contains all records, and you want to sum all unique records from `gt_ugtyt`?

how about this pseudo code:

```
loop at gt_ugtyt_temp assigning [line]
    loop at gt_ugtyt where stdate = [line]-stdate sttime = [line]-sttime (etc)
        [sum all values either changing [line] or put them in a new table]
    endloop.
endloop
```

Comment: i don't want to use loop for this. Because all rows of gt_ugtyt are using in loop at gt_ugtyt. In old code, working time is calculated (there is no loop for calculating each gt_ugtytrow's working time) and sum end of "loop at gt_ugtyt".